# How can I ensure that a remote image of a imageView will be shown in a window with a scrollView?

Tags: image, imageview, titanium, scrollview

I've tested a lot of things to solve my problem, but I have no idea now to fix it.
On the internet I found out, that the "load event" of the imageView could work, but it doesn't.

I have the following code:

```
var thisWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;


// Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
loader.open("GET","http://myserver/foo/")

// Send the HTTP request
loader.send();

// Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
loader.onload = function() 
{   
    var rest_result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
        contentWidth: 'auto',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        top:0,
        left:0,
        showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
        scrollType: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });

    var label_headline_general = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color:'#0066cc',
        text:'My Headline 1',
        font:{fontSize:14,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
        shadowColor: '#bfd9f2',
        shadowOffset:{x:1, y:1},
        textAlign:'left',
        width:'auto',
        height:'auto',
        left:5,
        top:6
    });

    var label_headline_main = Ti.UI.createLabel({   
        color:'#003366',
        text:rest_result.name,  
        font:{fontSize:18,fontWeight:'bold',fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
        shadowColor: '#ddeeff',
        shadowOffset:{x:1, y:1},    
        textAlign:'left',
        width:'auto',           
        height:'auto',
        left:5,
        top:label_headline_general.size.height + 5
    });

    // imageURI is something like: http://foo/myimage.png
    var imageURI = rest_result.image;

    if(imageURI == '')
    {
        imageURI = 'my-fallback-image.png';
    }

    var my_image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image:imageURI,
        defaultImage:'my-fallback-image.png',
        width:'auto',
        height:'auto',
        top:0,
        left:0
    });

    my_image.addEventListener('load',imageIsLoaded);

function imageIsLoaded(e) { 
    my_image.image = imageURI;
    my_image.show();
}

    scrollView.add(label_headline_general);
    scrollView.add(label_headline_main);
    scrollView.add(label_image);

    thisWin.add(scrollView);
}
```

In the Titanium-emulator the code works fine and the image, if the JSON had an image, were shown, but on the device it doesn't. On the device the default-image is shown. I think I have a timing problem (all elements are rendered faster than the image).

I tested the same approach with window and without any scrollView and it worked. In this case the image was loaded every time correct on every device.

How can I ensure, that the remote image in the imageView "my_image" is loaded in the scrollView and will be 100% shown?  Is there any technique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776031/detecting-imageview-load-error-appcelerator-titanium-mobile) post you can watch for the `load` event twice though that almost seems like a bug rather then feature.